# Can I fine-tune the again a gpt-3.5-turbo fine tuned model with more data?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I had fined tuned GPT 3.5 turbo model, can I fine tune that model again with more data to get better result.

I tried to fine tune model again but I cannot,is any possible way.

Is prompt is very in good to fine tune a model.Without prompt, can we get same result with prompt fine tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-fine tune existing fine tunes model. Just pass the name of your current fine-tuned model into the model parameter when creating a fine-tuning job.

```
client.fine_tuning.jobs.create(
  training_file="file-id123", 
  model="your current fine-tune model name"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you can fine-tune the open AI model again in the Incremential training way.

- The new data set submitted for fine tuning will create a new model by name which also contain your previous dataset.

Comment: What is the difference between a fine tuned model and re fine model in the term of performs for with same data type?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).